# BackGround Worker in c# to Parse the File List Recursively avoiding Acces Denied Exception 

Tags: c#, .net, file, backgroundworker, directory

I'm trying to list all the files from the a Folder/Drive including the Sub Directories while Ignoring the Access Denied Exception that arises when i use the Directory.GetFiles() method.

I have got the Method.The problem is that the Method involves recursive calls to itself, i cannot call the background worker recursively.How can i implement this method as a Background work.

```
 static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

    // First, process all the files directly under this folder
    try
    {
        files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
    }
    // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater
    // than the application provides.
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // This code just writes out the message and continues to recurse.
        // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you
        // can try to elevate your privileges and access the file again.
        log.Add(e.Message);
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            // In this example, we only access the existing FileInfo object. If we
            // want to open, delete or modify the file, then
            // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case
            // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
        }

        // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
        subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
        {
            // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
            WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
        }
    }            
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Very easy: just call this method inside your background-workers body-method.